# MongoDB Aggregation Match in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I need to aggregate data of countries where the region matches to some region provided and the languages (an array of objects) contains the language that is provided. I am completely new to MongoDB and im struggling to find an answer on this problem.
below the json file of the document as an example;

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"6499c2543163de51d8bcfc58"},
"name":"Åland Islands",
"topLevelDomain":[".ax"],
"alpha2Code":"AX",
"alpha3Code":"ALA",
"callingCodes":["358"],
"capital":"Mariehamn",
"altSpellings":["AX","Aaland","Aland","Ahvenanmaa"],
"region":"Europe",
"subregion":"Northern Europe",
"population":{"$numberInt":"28875"},
"latlng":[{"$numberDouble":"60.116667"},{"$numberDouble":"19.9"}],
"demonym":"Ålandish",
"area":{"$numberDouble":"1580.0"},
"gini":null,
"timezones":["UTC+02:00"],
"borders":[],
"nativeName":"Åland",
"numericCode":"248",
"currencies":[{"code":"EUR","name":"Euro","symbol":"€"}],
"languages":[{"iso639_1":"sv","iso639_2":"swe","name":"Swedish","nativeName":"svenska"}],
"translations":{"de":"Åland","es":"Alandia","fr":"Åland","ja":"オーランド諸島","it":"Isole Aland","br":"Ilhas de Aland","pt":"Ilhas de Aland","nl":"Ålandeilanden","hr":"Ålandski otoci","fa":"جزایر الند"},
"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
"regionalBlocs":[{"acronym":"EU","name":"European Union","otherAcronyms":[],"otherNames":[]}],
"cioc":""
}
```

In the snippet below you can see what I tried.

```
[
  {
    $match:
      /**
       * query: The query in MQL.
       */
      {
        region: "Africa",
        languages: {
          name: "French",
        },
      },
  },
]
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: If you use [_dot notation_](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-in-an-array-of-documents) , `"languages.name": "French"`, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
  {
    $match: { 
      $and: [
        { region: { $eq: "Africa" } },
        { "languages.name": { $eq: "French" } },
      ] 
    },
  },
]
```